# Transposition Cipher doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, encryption

This code should work as simple transposition cipher encryption and decryption. However, it only works with very small values for the key like 4. Can someone please help me find the error? It runs but if the number is bigger than 4, it won't encrypt the whole text. At the end it has to be able to encrypt and decrypt with a key up to 256. I'd appreciate any tips

```
def encrypt(text, key):
    encrypted_text = list(text)
    key %= len(text)  # Ensure the key is within the bounds of the text length


    for i in range(key, len(text), key):
        encrypted_text[i - key], encrypted_text[i] = encrypted_text[i], encrypted_text[i - key]

    return ''.join(encrypted_text)

def decrypt(encrypted_text, key):
    return encrypt(encrypted_text, key)  # Decryption is the same as encryption in this case

# Test the encryption and decryption
plaintext = "this is a test"
key = 2  # You can use any key value now
print(f"Original Text: {plaintext}")
print(f"Key: {key}")

encrypted_text = encrypt(plaintext, key)
print(f"Encrypted Text: {encrypted_text}")

decrypted_text = decrypt(encrypted_text, key)
print(f"Decrypted Text: {decrypted_text}")
```

I tried to adapt the encryption function. I'm new to programming so I don't recall everything I tried but I think there is some kind of error in the range. However, I'm not sure

Comment: 1) I don't think this is a transposition cipher (your algorithm looks way off). 2) The provided example doesn't decrypt using a second round of encryption (doesn't look to be a symmetrical key encryption method) 3)Your problem is `for i in range(key, len(text), key)` as this will skip over the last `key` values. for small numbers you just don't notice it, but the bug is always there since your loop doesn't reach them

Answer (score 0):

In testing out your code, the key issue was in the string/list slicing statement:

```
encrypted_text[i - key], encrypted_text[i] = encrypted_text[i], encrypted_text[i - key]
```

This produced the following unexpected terminal output.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Encrypt$ python3 Scramble.py 
Original Text: this is a test
Key: 2
Encrypted Text: ih ssia t sett
Decrypted Text:  hssait s teit
```

Instead of a substring referencing "encrypted_text[i]", which was one character too long, the element index needed to be "encrypted_text[i - 1]".  Since your program is relatively small, following is a refactored version of the code with the above refinement along with a tweak to allow for additional testing.

```
def encrypt(text, key):
    encrypted_text = list(text)
    key %= len(text)  # Ensure the key is within the bounds of the text length

    print("Key is:", key)

    if (key != 0):
        for i in range(key, len(text), key):
            encrypted_text[i - key], encrypted_text[i - 1] = encrypted_text[i - 1], encrypted_text[i - key] # Corrected
    else:
        print("Text was not encrypted/decrypted")

    return ''.join(encrypted_text)

def decrypt(encrypted_text, key):
    return encrypt(encrypted_text, key)  # Decryption is the same as encryption in this case

# Test the encryption and decryption
key = int(input("Enter a value between 1 and 256: "))   # Test with different keys

plaintext = "this is a test"

print(f"Original Text: {plaintext}")
print(f"Key: {key}")

encrypted_text = encrypt(plaintext, key)
print(f"Encrypted Text: {encrypted_text}")

decrypted_text = decrypt(encrypted_text, key)
print(f"Decrypted Text: {decrypted_text}")
```

The key points to note are:

- Correct the substring length when adjusting the portions of the full text per the key value.
- Adding a test to ensure that the chosen key is not the same value as the length of the text string.

With that, following are some tests of the refactored code.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Encrypt$ python3 Scramble.py 
Enter a value between 1 and 256: 2
Original Text: this is a test
Key: 2
Key is: 2
Encrypted Text: htsii  s aetst
Key is: 2
Decrypted Text: this is a test
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Encrypt$ python3 Scramble.py 
Enter a value between 1 and 256: 5
Original Text: this is a test
Key: 5
Key is: 5
Encrypted Text:  hist s aitest
Key is: 5
Decrypted Text: this is a test
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Encrypt$ python3 Scramble.py 
Enter a value between 1 and 256: 14
Original Text: this is a test
Key: 14
Key is: 0
Text was not encrypted/decrypted
Encrypted Text: this is a test
Key is: 0
Text was not encrypted/decrypted
Decrypted Text: this is a test
```

The main thing to take away is probably delve into some more tutorial literature as it pertains to strings, substrings, and lists.